# Перевод сообщения о переносе сообщения

Tags: дефект, локализация, нет-в-transifex, перенос-вопросов

Присутствует [проблема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/62/revisions) с переводом сообщения о переносе сообщения (о, как):

[image: перенесено]

В [transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40262684?key=f0dcc098a59bf91fd4c7c62f4d4a9a1c) есть строка, но она не содержит "from". Отдельно "from" не обнаруживается, вероятно, он зашит в код.