# Частично не переведено: "Сообщение перенесено сюда from ..."

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, ревизии

В [списке редакций](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/703404/revisions) вопроса, перенесенного с меты на ru.SO:

[image: from]

Искал этот отдельный "from" на transifex - не нашел.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291903/339911

Comment: Без вмешательства модераторов здесь не справится

Comment: @Duoxx модератор тут не помощник

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перевод сообщения о переносе сообщения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3855/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: @alexolut, вопрос может и дубликат, но тогда ответ должен быть там, а не здесь. А то у меня в очередной раз возникают сомнения, что мне стоит нажимать кнопку "Это решило мою проблему".

Comment: @insolor ну, я просто забыл, что ещё и на нашей Мете писал об этом. В принципе можно и тот мой старый вопрос как дубликат закрыть, чтобы ответ не переносить. Или же чтоб модератор объединил вопросы.

Comment: Пофикшено вроде.

Comment: @Suvitruf только надо бы «из» (или «с»), а не «от».

Comment: @alexolut нужно в трансе искать)

Comment: @alexolut хотя, если там перевод именно слова from, то оно может и "от" (like "от тебя/меня"). Если оно переиспользуется, то где-то всё равно косяк может быть.

Comment: @Suvitruf есть вот такой ключ: 5da618e8e4b89c66fe86e32cdafde142

Comment: @alexolut осталось только понять, где он используется? )

Comment: @Suvitruf можно поменять и проверить, забавно будет, если с миграцией вообще из другого места прилетает этот «от».

Comment: @alexolut попробуйте. Методом тыка определим)

Comment: @Suvitruf изменил. Посмотрим, когда базу дернут.

Comment: @Suvitruf еще бы “to” “в” найти ключик для полноты картины.

Comment: @Suvitruf и сделать его «на».

Comment: @alexolut  e12167aa0a7698e6ebc92b4ce3909b53

Comment: @Suvitruf там вообще какое-то «для», а не «в».

Comment: @alexolut мде =/

Answer (score 3):

Данный дефект зарегистрирован на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291903/339911). Пока разработчики особо не чешутся.

Плюсуйте, ставьте лайки, добавляйте в избранное, подписывайтесь на обновления, добавляйте больше [нытьё](/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%91) и может быть нас услышат.

Comment: Кто-то точно услышал, раз поправили )

Comment: @Suvitruf не факт, что услышано. Может просто кодревью случился :)