# Отсутствие перевода в сообщении о переносе сообщения

Tags: дефект, локализация, миграция

Был значит [такой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5739/%d0%a7%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%8e%d0%b4%d0%b0-from) вопрос. И вроде даже пофиксили перевод слова `from` на `c`.

Но почему-то, даже несмотря на [это](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291903/translation-for-migrated-posts-in-revisions), все еще слово `to` не пофикшено, хотя [Suvitruf - Andrei Apanasik](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/15479/suvitruf-andrei-apanasik) почему-то [писал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5739/%d0%a7%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%8e%d0%b4%d0%b0-from#comment32785_5741), мол пофикшено?!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так пофиксится?

Comment: Что-то опять сломали. Надо на MSE писать, хз, где эта строка запряталась. Ну и заодно, [tsya.ru](https://tsya.ru/).